# WoW Addon - Collecting related data from different events

Tags: events, lua, add-on, world-of-warcraft

I want to link two different WoW events together. I need some information from both events and store them together in a simple table. Also it is important that the data of the second event is stored *only* if the first event even fired!

In my case its the name of a creature from [COMBAT_LOG_EVENT_UNFILTERED](http://wowprogramming.com/docs/events/COMBAT_LOG_EVENT_UNFILTERED) and the reputation gained from [COMBAT_TEXT_UPDATE](http://wowprogramming.com/docs/events/COMBAT_TEXT_UPDATE). **The reputation should only be stored, if it is gained from killing a creature.** I am currently doing that with a temporary table to link those. It stores the name from the first event and will be readable in the second event. Here's the simplified code for that:

```
nehFragger_ReputationDB = {}   -- The actual database for my AddOn.
local tempKillLog = {}   -- A table that I use to link the different events.

function nehFraggerFrame_OnLoad(frame)
    frame:RegisterEvent("COMBAT_LOG_EVENT_UNFILTERED")
    frame:RegisterEvent("COMBAT_TEXT_UPDATE")
end

function nehFraggerFrame_OnEvent(frame, event, ...)

    local arg1, eventType, arg3, arg4, sourceName, arg6, arg7, destGUID, destName = select(1, ...)
    if (event == "COMBAT_LOG_EVENT_UNFILTERED") then
        if (eventType == "PARTY_KILL") then
            tempKillLog.creatureGUID = destGUID   -- The unique identifier of the creature.
            tempKillLog.creatureName = destName    -- The creature name that I need.
        end
    end

    local eventType, faction, reputation = select(1, ...)
    if (event == "COMBAT_TEXT_UPDATE") then
        if (eventType == "FACTION") then
            local GUID = TempKillLog.creatureGUID
            if (string.upper(string.sub(GUID, 1 , 8)) == "CREATURE") then   -- Make sure the link-table data really is a creature.
                local creatureName = tempKillLog.creatureName   -- The name from my link-table.
                local reputationGain = reputation   -- The reputation that I need.
                -- Simply store the stuff to the database table for this faction:
                nehFragger_ReputationDB[faction] = {}
                nehFragger_ReputationDB[faction].creatureName = creatureName
                nehFragger_ReputationDB[faction].reputationGain = reputationGain
            end
        end
    end

end
```

This works...sort of. There are several problems with that *(see below)*.

**My question here is:**
Is there a possibility to either
- get some unique identifier for the source of different events in general (like the `destGUID` of `COMBAT_LOG_EVENT`) to connect those
- or is there an even simpler way to get the reputation of a kill (including creature and reputation information) like in the case of my AddOn?

**Some more things to consider:**
I have also tried to use the current time in both events to check if these are fired within say 0.01 seconds. That erases loads of problems I have encountered, but will still fail in certain circumstances. If, for example, you finish one of these new Legion world-quests by killing a creature and then gain the reputation for the quest itself. That's still within the timeframe, regardless of how small it is.

Another problem is, if you kill more than one (say 5) creature at a time, then the first event `COMBAT_LOG_EVENT_UNFILTERED` first fires 5 times in a row, and THEN the second event `COMBAT_TEXT_UPDATE` fires 5 times. In this case, all the 5 logs in my `nehFragger_ReputationDB` have the correct amount of reputation gained but all of them with the name of the last creature killed/processed...

I would really like to use the `GUID` for both events to link them, but I cannot get the one of the second event - if there even exists one. That would be the cleanest and safest way in my opinion.
Or, like already mentioned, a dedicated WoW event for this. But I didn't find one.

I hope somebody can help me here or provide some food for thought.